# Populate database with IEnumerable objects from CSV file

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have a CSV file containing all Products from which I have a method in a new class converting them into C# Product objects which get stored in a variable of type IEnumerable:

```
public class ReadCSVFile
{
    public List<Product> ProductsList;

    public ReadCSVFile()
    {

        var path = @"/Content/TrendyDinersLimited_Self_ProductUpdateTemplate.csv";

        var CSVProducts = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1)
                          let columns = line.Split(',')
                          select new Product
                          {
                              Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                              Name = columns[1],
                              Price = int.Parse(columns[4])
                          };
    }
}
```

My question is, now that I have a list of Products from the CSV file, how should I populate them into my database (as a one time import)? Usually, the admin would create a category first, then click on a category to add products.

I am using an ASP.NET MVC template in Visual Studio and I have three main controllers: HomeController(displays categories and products), CategoryController(Admin Authorised), ProductController(Admin Authorised). I am also using a direct connection string to a Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Are you using an ORM, or straight connection to the database?

Comment: The latter - straight connection to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices. If you are writing code as a one time import utility, then you can directly connect to SQL Server to insert data.

```
        string sqlInsertStmt = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT (id,name,price) VALUES (@id, @name, @price)";
        string connectionString = "sqlserver connection string";

        //sample connection string can be like
        //connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            foreach (var product in CSVProducts)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlInsertStmt;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", product.Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", product.Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", product.Price);
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch(SqlException e)
                    {
                        //log exception and handle error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Examples for [SQL server connection strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sqlserver)

But if you want something more maintainable, you can use EF6 as your ORM layer.
Please read this article that explains how to [get started with EF6 and existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I am attempting this, but did you mean cmd.CommandText rather than cmd.CommandString?

Comment: Yes, it is Command Text... sorry for the typo. I have updated my answer

Comment: You can call it inside ReadCSVFile after reading data into CSVProducts variable. You might as well call the class ProductsLoader. It is bad practice to do some heavy operations inside a constructor method. You should probably create two methods. GetProducts that returns  List of Product and then another method called SaveProducts, that takes List of Products as input and perform save to database. And then call these two methods from your business layer or MVC controller.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd use Dapper.Net for something simple like this.

If use Dapper.Contrib (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/)
you can decorate your class with the table and key attributes to make life easier for yourself

```
[Table ("Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can insert like this

```
var connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
        foreach(var product in CSVProducts){        
            connection.Insert(product);
        }
    }
```